# Swift Deep Flatten Array Property

Tags: arrays, swift, flatten

I have the following code to create a `Person` class and have an array of people.

```
class Person {
    let name: String
    var children: [Person]

    init() {
        //removing init code to make question shorter, but just setting the variables passed in to the variables in the class
    }
}

var people: [Person] = [Person]()
var personA: Person = Person.init(name: "Bob Smith")
var personB: Person = Person.init(name: "Tom Smith")
var personC: Person = Person.init(name: "Billy Smith")
var personD: Person = Person.init(name: "Steve Smith")
var personE: Person = Person.init(name: "Steve Smith")

personA.children.append(personB)
personB.children.append(personD)
personB.children.append(personC)
personD.children.append(personE)

people.append(personA)
```

So at this point I have an array `people` with 1 person in it. That is all one section of my code that is working perfectly.

I have a separate section where I'm trying to transform this `people` array to basically flatten it. I have tried the following code unsuccessfully.

```
people.flatMap({ [$0, $0.children] }).filter({ $0 is Person }) as! [Person]
```

That code doesn't work at all. I have tried to make slight adjustments to it and have gotten errors and warnings such as `Cannot convert value of type '[Any]' to closure result type 'String?'` and `Expression implicitly coerced from '[Person]?' to Any`.

That second warning I tried changing it from `[$0, $0.children]` to `[$0, $0.children ?? nil]` assuming that would fix the problem. If `children` is `nil` I basically want it to move on and not put anything there since there is no children. But making that change continued to throw the same error.

But basically what I want is to take `people` from above and transform it from 1 element (`personA`) to 5 elements (`personA`, `personB`, `personD`, `personE`, `personC`).

Basically I have the following array (including the `children` property).

```
- personA
    - personB
        - personD
            - personE
        - personC
```

I want to take that array and flatten it recursively (deep flatten). Like the following.

```
- personA
- personB
- personD
- personE
- personC
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think the problem starts with `children` being an Optional. Do you need to distinguish between `nil` and an empty array?

Comment: @GaryMakin You are totally correct. An empty array in this case is basically the same as `nil`. No children in the array or `nil` same difference.

Comment: @GaryMakin I was able to remove the `?` from the `children`, but still not able to achieve what I want.

Comment: I haven't tried running the code yet, just edited it in Xcode to look for compile errors and warnings.

Comment: @MartinR is right. That other issue will solve the flattening.

Comment: Thanks @GaryMakin and MartinR, I was able to solve the issue! Thanks so much.